# Second order PDE whose operator "changes type".

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\{e_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,T])$, and assume we have the following Cauchy problem

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u= \sum_{j,l=1}^{N} e_j(t)e_l(t) \partial_{x_j x_l}^2 u\\
u(0,\vec{x})=u_0\in\mathbb R.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I am not very familiar with PDEs but I assume this is a degenerate system, because the differential operator "changes" its type as time goes by (in general a basis can take positive and negative values, making the quadratic form neither positive (semi) definite nor negative (semi)definte.

Is there some hope to find a existence result for this problem?

I appreciate any suggestion you can offer.

Comment: What is a CONS?

Comment: @StarBug a Complete Orthonormal System, let me fix it

Comment: A basis for $L^2([0,T])$ won’t be finite, so you just summing over the first $N$ terms in the basis in an infinite set. Was that what you were intending?

Comment: Also, your PDE is parabolic since the right hand side of the PDE can be written as $\sum_{i,j=1}^N \partial_i (a_{ij} \partial_j u ) $ where $a_{ij}(t) = e_i(t) e_j(t)$ and $a_{ij}$ is positive definite. You can see this since for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \zeta_i \zeta_j = (\sum_i \zeta_i e_i)^2$ which is zero iff $\zeta =0$ by linear independence.

Comment: So there is definitely hope for the existence of weak solutions though normally the coefficients are assumed to be in $L^\infty$. See for example Chapter 7 of Partial Differential Equations by Evans

Comment: @Globemaster17 regarding your first question, the answer is yes, of course the basis is not finite, and I am just taking the sum over the first $N$ terms (this is like a finite dimensional Gross Laplacian).

Comment: By the way I didn't realized that the quadratic form was actually the square of the sum, from the start I assumed that it wasn't positive definite! And actually the basis I am cared about is in L∞ so everything works just fine!